# Why is k-means clustering producing such bad results?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset with 60 000 rows and 19 columns ( I will leave a sample below) and I am trying to make clusters. Using the k-means algorithm I am getting a very low score.

**Dataset Sample**

[image]

Since some of my columns are categorical variables I proceded to transform them in continous using dictionaries variables as follows:

```
def education_dict(data):
    education_dict= {
        "Bachelors": 0,
        "Graduate Degree": 1,
        "High School": 2,
        "Partial College": 3,
        "Partial High School": 4
    }
    data["IDEducation"]=data["Education"].map(education_dict)
```

After converting the categorical variable to a continuous variable I delete the old variable.

After that I do the normalization of the data ( all columns since now all of them are continuous) and I proceed to the k-means algorithm.

```
mms=MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(data)
Xnorm=mms.transform(data)
print(Xnorm.min(axis=0))
print(Xnorm.max(axis=0))
print(Xnorm.shape)

km=KMeans(n_clusters=10,n_init=1000,max_iter=800,random_state=42)
y_kmeans=km.fit_predict(Xnorm)

#Clustering evaluation
#Silhouette score

#the closest to 1 the better
silSc=silhouette_score(data,y_kmeans,metric="euclidean")
print("Silhouette score: " , round(silSc,3))
print("\nThese measures need grand truth\n")
```

The cluster evaluation is returning me a silhouette score of about 0.08 and this is to low. If I run hieraquical clustering, which is not suited to big datasets like mine, I get a score of about 0.54

```
segmentation=["single","average","complete"]
results=[]
for met in segmentation:
    distance_matrix=linkage(Xnorm,method=met,metric="euclidean")
    #Assign cluster lables
    cluster_labels=fcluster(distance_matrix,3,criterion="maxclust")

    silSc=silhouette_score(data,cluster_labels,metric="euclidean")
    print("Silhouette score: " , round(silSc,3))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried visualizing your data? Do you know for a fact that there are clusters within your data, which you are trying to capture through K-means? For all I know, the data points you have are uniformly distributed with no reasons to expect any clusters. Meanwhile, were the hierarchical clustering results meaningful? Or did it just split the data roughly in half, randomly, and give you a high silhouette score, but no meaningful insight?

Comment: Furthermore, you've used [ordinal encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-hot-encoding-for-categorical-data/) to convert your categorical variables into continuous variables. This isn't recommended as the numbers you get have no real "meaning"; for example `0<1<2` makes sense, but `Bachelors < Graduate < Highschool` doesn't. K-means expect distance between datapoints to mean something, but ordinal encoding is terrible at encoding "meaning" for K-means to use.

Comment: @mimocha so how do you recommended me to handle my categorical variables?

Comment: I'd actually recommend you [don't use K-means for categorical variables](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24) to begin with. But if you must, then [one-hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) is a good place to start. However, this doesn't guarantee that you will get a high silhouette score, just that the score you get *might* be meaningful.